# Row height of table is not reducing using matplotlib table.scale() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a table using matplotlib . The table is showing keys for different markers in the graph. Now I want to reduce the height of each row present in the table in the same proportion. 
I have tried using-

```
table.scale(xscale,yscale)
```

But whatever value I give in yscale row height remains the same.
I have tried giving-

```
table.scale(2,2)
table.scale(2,1)
table.scale(2,0.5)
```

The row height remains the same for all the three cases.How to reduce the row height for table?? Is there some alternative way of doing it as mostly all the articles suggests using scale only.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem. If you use `table.scale(1,2)` the rows will be twice as heigh as initially. If that is not the case for you, you need to supply a [mcve] (i.e. a runnable code) in the question, such that people have a chance finding out what prevents that from working in that special case.